# DDD ValueObject and Enumeration , is there any good way to implement serialization?

Tags: serialization, domain-driven-design, enumeration

In DDD, [Value Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/microservice-ddd-cqrs-patterns/implement-value-objects) and [Enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/microservice-ddd-cqrs-patterns/enumeration-classes-over-enum-types) are quite beautiful so that I want use both two in the daily program logic, not only domain logic. When use customized value objects and enumerations, serialization problem is coming : should I implemented all the value objects and enumeration with `System.Text.Json.JsonConverter<T>`  , or is there any good way to handle serialization and deserialization ?

Update:
   to make it clear, `Eumeration` demo as below(`ValueObject` derived classes are same.):

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(CustomizedConverter))]
public class CustomizedEnumeration1 : Enumeration 
{
     public string Customized { get; protected set; }

     public ... // some other customized property or class

     public CustomizedEnumeration(int id, string name, string customized) : base(id, string) {
        Customized = customized;
     } 
}

public class Customized2 : Enumeration 
{ ... }

public class OtherCustomized: Enumeration 
{ ... }
```

In DDD, properties sometimes are sealed by `protected/private setter`,   deserialization has no right to set the value. Many derived classes can't deserialize as expected, so we have to rewrite serialization with `System.Text.Json.JsonConverter<T>` one by one. rewrite every derived `Enumeration` / `Valueobject` converter is not good, can any one point out any easy abstraction for that ?

Comment: not clear to me what you mean by Value Object and Enumeration - maybe a short example of what you mean there? Tnx

Comment: @AdrianNasui thanks for the tip, question updated.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your desired result. You need to switch to NewtonsoftJson serialization.

Call this in Startup.cs in the ConfigureServices method:

```
services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();
```

After this, your constructor will be called by deserialization for classes with private setter.

There is no need for custom converters.

For reference, I am using ASP Net Core 3.1

Comment: thanks, I'll deep dive into newtonsoft, and compare the difference.